# Symfony 4 AbstractController Issue with Parameter Count

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to write an API in Symfony 4. I've hit a problem with my controller methods when trying to use DependencyInjection for a service API class I created. I've tried several different ways to write the code and can not figure it out.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

I can make a getNext() (instead of get() below) method and the code will function as expected, but if I try to use a get() method I will get an error. These are the basic classes involved. Most of the code has been removed.

```
class AppointmentController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/appointment/getNext", name="appointment/getNext")
     * 
     */
    public function get(string $id = null, CernerFhir $fhirApi)
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        ...more code...
    }
}        

class CernerFhir
{

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->params = $params;
        }
    }
}
```

Warning: Declaration of App\Controller\AppointmentController::get(?string $id, App\Service\CernerFhir $fhirApi) should be compatible with Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::get(string $id)

Comment: The error is because AbstractController already has a method named get.  And while not directly related to your question, there is no need to create a request object inside of a controller action.  Just inject it.

Comment: As above - you've chosen a method name that already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbstractController uses an interface that defines a get() method with a specific number of parameter and return type. If you wan't to overwrite it's get method (which i do no recommend), you have to write it so that it's compatible with it's definition in the interface.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: I understand the error, but I'm not sure how to correct it. It seems like the dependency injection objects should not count towards the number of parameters, but they do. To fix this, should I drop the dependency injection and then try to build out the objects manually? I'm not sure how to get or build the global logger and parameter bag objects.

Comment: 1) Rename your method to something else, like getNext()
2) Depedency injection only works in a class constructor, add a __construct method that stores your api in a variable in your controller and you'll be fine.

Comment: I tried to do method "2" with a separate class; public function __construct(CernerFhir $api) { ... }, but then I get a error of two few arguments. I think it's complaining about the logger and the parameter bag. "Too few arguments to function App\Service\CernerFhirAppointment::__construct()"

Comment: Thank you Sodium. I was finally able to figure it out. Dependency injection did work in the controller's constructor, but not in my service class constructor. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Dependency autowiring should work out of the box for any class stored in your src folder, only exceptions i know of are entities and entity listeners. If you need help with that you should post it in a new topic.